# Catch an exception from pyqt4 gui

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I have an application which uses the IPython QTconsole as a command line interface and a PyQt4 gui as a graphical interface. The GUI is simply set up to call console commands as slots. I'm still developing this, so there are a lot of bugs. When I call the command from my IPython window, I receive any error message that happened, but when the GUI calls one of these methods, any error silently occurs. How can I have the GUI print out errors as expected?

Comment: Can you show an example of how you call these "console commands"? And what are they - OS system calls, python calls, or what?

Comment: They are python function calls. They are called through the interactive IPython shell: interactiveshell, 2735, run_code, exec code_obj in self.user_global_ns,

Comment: Again, how are you calling them? Do you use `subprocess`? `os.exec`? You could show us *some* code...

Comment: I run the command ipython qtconsole -c "%run main.py" which calls a script that starts a QtMainWindow, which runs the GUI thread, then I run the commands in the IPython console.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) to print info about unhandled exceptions to a window.